# Algorithm to find ideal starting spot in a circle

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So the problem I have been debating is as such:

Your are given an array of integers representing a circle. Then, you have to pick spot in the circle to start. From the place you start, you compare the value at the array to number of steps you took to get there and if the steps are less than or equal to the number, include it in your final set. Find the place to start so that you have the most elements in your set.

```
ex, a=[0, 1, 2]

If you start at index=0, then:
a[0]=0 < =0 so 0 is included
a[1]=1 < =1 so 1 is included
a[2]=2 < =2 so 2 is included

final set: {0,1,2}


If you start at index=1, then:
a[1]=1 > 0 so 1 is NOT included
a[2]=2 > 1 so 2 is NOT included here we loop back around
a[0]=0 > 2 so 0 is included

final set: {0}

If you start at index=2, then:
a[2]=2 > 0 so 2 is NOT included, here we loop back around
a[0]=0 < = 1 so 0 is included 
a[1]=1 < = 2 so 1 is included

final set: {0,1}
```

So in this trivial case, starting position index=0 is the best position as it results in the final set with the most elements. Now the brute force method of finding this is obvious, but I am trying to find a more efficient method. My attempts so far have been to examine trying to find the max intersect of viable starting ranges calculated for each element in the array. Also, I feel like dynamic programming can be used in some way to help make the solution but I can't seem to identify exactly how.

Comment: (1) Are numbers allowed to repeat? (2) There may be more than 1 position yielding the set of optimal size, do we stop at the first position found?

Comment: @hidefromkgb So to clarify, (1) the numbers are bound to the range 0 <= x <= n where n is the length of the array and (2) if there are multiple max positions that result in the same sized final set, you stop at the first one

Answer (score 2):

This is [a problem of ongoing contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/university-codesprint). It's illegal and considered as cheating to ask for solutions during contest.

You can ask for help providing what you've already tried once the contest ends.

Comment: Meh. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AndrewLi I posted it as answer to get attention so that if anyone intends to post answer, they can easily notice it.

Comment: @KaidulIslam Understood. We should keep this post anyways for evidence of cheating.